# MS SQL Server 2014 | "Recursive" delete through a star schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day all,

I'll try and be as succinct as possible.

I have a star schema with a fact table in the centre, surrounded by a set of dimension tables. Each dimension table snowflakes into further dimension tables.

Pseudo-visual example:

`Super_FAC >--FK-- First_DIM --NK-- Snowflake_DIM`

(`>-` indicates an n-to-1 relationship, `--` indicates a 1-to-1 relationship, `FK` indicates a foreign key and `NK` indicates a natural key)

**What I am trying to achieve:** I'm trying to find an elegant solution the the problem by recursively deleting records from the fact table, up the chain into the first dimension table and then into the snowflake dimension table, with the minimal amount of scripting. (No triggers allowed)

**What I have done:**

```
DELETE Super_FAC
    FROM Snowflake_DIM AS SDIM INNER JOIN
    First_DIM AS FDIM ON SDIM.NK = FDIM.NK INNER JOIN -- For brevity, key is more complex
    Super_FAC AS SFAC ON FDIM.FK = SFAC.FK
    WHERE SDIM.ModifiedDate >= DeltaDate

DELETE First_DIM
    FROM Snowflake_DIM AS SDIM INNER JOIN
    First_DIM AS FDIM ON SDIM.NK = FDIM.NK -- For brevity, key is more complex
    WHERE SDIM.ModifiedDate >= DeltaDate

DELETE Snowflake_DIM
    FROM Snowflake_DIM AS SDIM INNER JOIN
    WHERE SDIM.ModifiedDate >= DeltaDate
```

Is there a more *elegant* solution? Using something like a CTE perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

M

Comment: In this case you want to delete from many different tables. This cannot be combined to the *one-big-statement*. You'll need a `DELETE tbl ...` for each target table. What is *elegant*? You might use a declared table variable to collect all rows (tablename and key) and later use this table to write your `DELETE` statements as *one-liner*...

Comment: Btw: a CTE will not help you. You can use this CTE in one statement only. Therefore you could use a declared table variable (something like `declare @tbl TABLE(TargetTable VARCHAR(100),ID INT)`) to collect all rows to delete and then use something like `DELETE FROM TheActualTarget WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM @tbl WHERE TargetTable='TheActualTarget')`

Comment: Have you considered an ON DELETE trigger?

Comment: @RichBenner, OP wrote *No triggers allowed* ...

Comment: @Shnugo aah, didn't see that. cheers for clarifying.